# Get bad values inside a loop

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got a method for generate url

But I have a little problem when I'm adding the condition if/else, he returns me only the first value and  not all

This is my code :

```
    public generateUrl(components: any, versions: any) {
        const keys: any[] = Object.keys(components);  //['toto','titi','tata','tutu']
        for (const component of keys) {
            const versions = components[component].artifacts.map((arti) => {
                return {
                    component: arti.name,
                    type: arti.type,
                    version: versions[arti.name],
                };
            });


            console.log(versions);  // Display only the first one and not all 
            //[ { component: 'toto',
            //    type: 'npm',
            //    version: '1' } ]


            for (const i in versions) {
                const v = versions[i];

                // here i'm adding the confition

                if (v.type === "jar") {
                    const urlTest =
                        v.component +
                        "/" +
                        v.version +
                        ".jar"
                    
                        return urlTest;

                } else if (v.type === "npm") {
                    const urlTest =
                        v.component +
                        "/" +
                        v.version +
                        ".npm"
                    
                        return urlTest;
                        
                }
                } else if (v.type === "rpm") {
                    const urlTest =
                        v.component +
                        "/" +
                        v.version +
                        ".rpm"                  
                        return urlTest;
                        
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to retrieve all values and not only the first one.

THanks for your help

Comment: Can you explain your desired result

Comment: That's because you `return` from the first iteration of the loop. If you want to retrieve all values, you must collect them in an array or other data structure, instead of returning only a single value.

Comment: Why is the method marked as `async` if it doesn't use `await` anywhere?

Comment: Ok so I need to collect into a array. This is my mistake for async ...

Comment: Also you should not use `for (const i in versions)` loop to iterate over arrays. `for-in` is not the same as `for-of`. I'd suggest to use `map` if you need to collect transformed values,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.reduce` to accumulate your values which match up to your type, instead of returning after match.

Also the `for-in` loop is to enumerate over enumerable object properties of a object, if I am not mistaken then `versions` is an array.

Working example below -

```js
const data = [ 
    { 
        component: 'toto',
        type: 'npm',
        version: '1'
    },
    { 
        component: 'tata',
        type: 'jar',
        version: '2'
    },
    { 
        component: 'titi',
        type: 'rpm',
        version: '3'
    } 
];

const types = ['npm', 'jar', 'rpm'];
const testUrls = data.reduce((acc, { component, type, version }) => {
    if (types.includes(type)) {
        acc.push(`${component}/${version}.${type}`);
    }
    
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(testUrls);
```

Answer (score 0):

like @Bergi said

> That's because you return from the first iteration of the loop.

else you can try something like that, by using `reduce`:

Working example:

```
type Component = {
  artifacts: any[];
};

type Version = {
    [key: string]: string;
}

class Test {

    public static GenerateUrl(components: Component[], versions: Version) {
        return components.reduce((acc: any, { artifacts }) => {
            return artifacts.reduce((acc, { type, name }) => {
                acc.push(`${name}@${versions[name]}.${type}`);
                return acc.flat();
            }, acc);
        }, []);
    }
};

const versions: any = {
  "titi": "1.0.0",
  "toto": "1.8.1",
  "tata": "1.2.5"
}

const components = [
  {
    artifacts: [
      {
        type: "jar",
        name: "titi"
      },
      {
        type: "npm",
        name: "titi"
      },
      {
        type: "rpm",
        name: "toto"
      },
      {
        type: "rpm",
        name: "tata"
      }
    ]
  }
]
console.log(Test.GenerateUrl(components, versions)); // ["titi@1.0.0.jar","titi@1.0.0.npm","toto@1.8.1.rpm","tata@1.2.5.rpm"]
```